# Edições: sem pergunta no corpo do texto ou com código primeiro

Tags: debate, edição, formatação

Tenho visto muitas perguntas nos formatos:

**1.** Título com o erro (*em inglês e negrito*) e código grande e confuso no corpo do texto. Ex:

- [Cannot read property 'collection' of undefined](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/324345/cannot-read-property-collection-of-undefined)

Nessa pergunta apenas melhorei a formatação, mas não acho que melhorou muito.

**2.**   Título com o erro (*em inglês e negrito*), código grande e confuso no corpo do texto (*que pode ser a saída de erro ou apenas o código que o usuário está tentando executar*) e logo abaixo uma tentativa de texto de pergunta. Ex:

- [Servidor com socket em Java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/324253/servidor-com-socket-em-java)

Nessa pergunta, uma melhor formatação seria a pergunta antes e o código depois?

Em casos assim, vale a edição ou o melhor é sinalizar como *não está clara o suficiente* e deixar um comentário sugerindo uma melhoria?

Comment: Na minha opinião o texto deve vir antes, caso contrário o código aparece do ar, e a pessoa começa a ler o código sem ter noção do que está a ler.

Comment: Votei para fechar as duas.

Comment: Ao meu ver, o que importa é que a pergunta esteja clara, a formatação **geralmente** ajuda, mas não necessariamente. É possível ter uma pergunta bem formulada sem nenhum texto no corpo, basta ter comentários no código. Você pode sempre editar, se achar que isso irá melhorar a pergunta, caso o autor ou a comunidade não gostar, é só desvazer. Uma dica: quando for editar perguntas, retire snippets inúteis, por exemplo, com código PHP, usando bibliotecas não importadas ou quando o resultado é irrelevante